# When was water created?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, creation, genesis-bereishith

Bereishit 1 goes into detail on when and how Hashem created various things in creation. One thing I notice though is that there is no specific detail on how or when water was created. It just sort of "shows up" after G-d creats the heavens and the earth and is never explained.

> :בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ: וְהָאָ֗רֶץ הָֽיְתָ֥ה תֹ֨הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ וְח֖שֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵ֣י תְה֑וֹם וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם
>
> In the beginning, G-d created the heavens and the earth. And the earth was formless and void, and darkness covered the surface of the deep, and the spirit of G-d was hovering over the face of the water.

Where did the water come from?

Comment: I see a problem with your first statement _"Bereishit 1 goes into detail on when and how Hashem created various things in creation"_. I think we should not take Bereyshis as a description of the process, but a very general framework.

Comment: Some say שמים of the first verse include מים.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78616/603

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pirkê D'Rabbi Eliezer ([ch. 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.3.6?with=all&lang=bi)) states that water was created on the first day:

> שמונה דברים נבראו ביום ראשון, ואלו הן: .... ורוח ומים, שנאמר ורוח אלהים מרחפת על פני המים

Trans.:

> Eight things were created on the first day, namely... wind (spirit) and water, as it said, "And the wind of God was moving upon the surface of the waters".