# Did the Egyptians know that Bnei Yisrael had light during Makas Choshech?

Tags: bo, plagues-makkos

Did the Egyptians knows that *Bnei Yisrael* had light during *Makas Choshech*, the plague of darkness?

Comment: Questions for specification: Are you asking whether they knew while it was happening or afterwards? What assumptions are you making in the question about how the Egyptians experienced the darkness? If a global, external phenomenon deductive answers to this will probably be very different from if you are considering it to have been a personal. . . medical one. Ref. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13624

Comment: @WAF No, I was asking if they knew DURING the plague.

Comment: I would imagine that some were smart enough to realize that the Jews probably had light, as they knew that most Jews were not affected by any of the plagues